# Valid Dates in AppEngine forms (Beginner)

Tags: django, google-app-engine

In AppEngine, I have a form that prompts a user for a date.    The problem is that when the clicks enter there is an error: "Enter a Valid Date"

How do I make my Form accept (for example) `%d-%b-%Y` as the date format?
Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

```
# Model and Forms
class Task(db.Model):
  name=db.StringProperty()
  due=db.DateProperty()

class TaskForm(djangoforms.ModelForm): 
  class Meta: 
    model = Task 

# my get function has the following.
# using "now" for example. Could just as well be next Friday.
tmStart = datetime.now()  
form = TaskForm(initial={'due': tmStart.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")})
template_values = {'form': form }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply specify a custom field (and optionally, widget) in your TaskForm for that field, and set the properties as appropriate - see the [django forms docs](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/newforms/) for details on how to specify fields.